# Run rsync on every save in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rsync, vscode-extensions, remote-server

I have a repository on my local system and am testing my changes on a remote server. I am using VSCode for development. I want that on every save, rsync should run in background and sync the changes in the current local file with remote. How can I achieve this with VSCode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using [Save and Run](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wk-j.save-and-run) vscode extension for syncing code between local and remote server whenever I hit save in VSCode. Following is the configuration I am using.

```
"saveAndRun": {
  "commands": [
    {
      "match": ".*",
      "cmd": "rsync -av --no-owner ${file} {destination folder}${relativeFile}",
      "useShortcut": false,
      "silent": false
    },
  ]
}
```

The output generated when the `rsync` command is run can been seen in VSCode terminal. You can add the above configuration in `.vscode/settings.json` file. You can learn more about editing settings.json file [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Answer (score 2):

The [Sync-Rsync extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-ext.sync-rsync) is designed to do this.

Comment: It's good to give examples

Answer (score 1):

Here is extension code which uses the `onDidSaveTextDocument` event to run code after a file is saved. The code uses the `exec` function of the `child_process` package to run a command. In this case, it launches the chrome browser.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as path from 'path';

import * as cp from 'child_process';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext)
{
    vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument((d) =>
    {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Document saved:" + path.basename(d.fileName));

        const start = (process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'open' : process.platform == 'win32' ? 'start' : 'xdg-open');
        cp.exec(start + ' chrome ' );
    });
}
```